# Python dictionary key-value name

Tags: python

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
b = [24, 53, 88, 32, 45, 24, 88, 53, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]
```

These are the list for the same

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid data structure. A dict can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: process your output from the constructed dict like so: for el in d.items():
    print("ID:" + str(el[0]), "Lottery" + str(el[1]))

Comment: Put ID & Lottery in namedtuple or a dict of itself.

Comment: You could create a list of dicts from your `d`: `[{"ID": k, "Lottery": v} for k, v in d.items()]`.

Comment: As you edited it, what is the question now ?

Answer (score 3):

**Your expected output is not valid data structure**. You can closely achieve this with list of dictionary in python,

```
result = []
for k,v in d.items():
    result.append({"ID": k, "Lottery": v})

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[ 
 {'ID': 0, 'Lottery': [24, 53, 88]},
 {'ID': 1, 'Lottery': [32, 45, 24, 88, 53]}, 
 {'ID': 2, 'Lottery': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66]},
 {'ID': 3, 'Lottery': [77]}
]
```

**DEMO:** https://rextester.com/XNBFFD14330

Comment: @devopio you can mark it as accepted with green tick

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a dictionary of dictionaries that you later convert to a list of dictionaries.

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
b = [24, 53, 88, 32, 45, 24, 88, 53, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]

d = { i:{"ID":i, "Lottery":[]} for i in a }
for i,v in zip(a,b): d[i]["Lottery"].append(v)
d = [*d.values()]

print(d)
# [{'ID': 0, 'Lottery': [24, 53, 88]}, {'ID': 1, 'Lottery': [32, 45, 24, 88, 53]}, {'ID': 2, 'Lottery': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66]}, {'ID': 3, 'Lottery': [77]}]
```